# Silex security.access_rules for api

Tags: security, silex

I'm trying to understand how Silex's firewall and security access rules works in relation to a path. Does this only work if you are trying to access this via a login form? Can you use the rules sent back from an api check (see [Proper way to configure Silex Firewall to use api keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342423/proper-way-to-configure-silex-firewall-to-use-api-keys) , which I have working ). I want to be able to set this up in the SecurityServiceProvider if at all possible and not in the controller.

Is this possible?

Edit: Adding the security firewall piece..

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'unsecured' => array(
            'pattern' => new RequestMatcher('^/api/brand/get'))
    ),

    'security.access_rules' => array(
        array('^/api/brand/get', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
        array('^/api/account/get', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
        array('^/.+$', 'ROLE_USER'),
        array('^/', '')
    )
));
```

Comment: Why your firewall is called unsecured, do you mean public access to ^/api/brand/get (I don't think so, in your access rules you create a constraint for admin access only)? Also you're missing an authentication method in your firewall so no authentication will be called...

Comment: You're referring to [Definig a custom Authentication Provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-authentication-provider)? Let me research that and add it in.

Comment: I'm also following a thread I [think you've replied to](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/silex-php/FRi8nI5mK3Q)

Comment: Yes, that was mine, the links there are very helpful. When I've told you that you're missing an authentication method I mean any (custom or Symfony's default), but if you're trying to create an API token authentication, that would be, indeed, custom (following the link to Symfony's doc, you'll see how to configure it)

Answer (score 1):

**Symfony Security component works in a two way steps: authentication and authorization.**

The **authentication** part is when the client tells the server who is (s)he (usually with some secret known only by both parties, ej. a password, or in your case an API token). When the server checks that the credentials are valid, the authentication is successful and then comes the second part, authorization (usually in web applications once a client is authenticated the authentication information is stored in the session so in later requests the client does not need to send again the credentials and follow the authentication process, but in an API token authentication process usually the client is required to send the API token every time, so no session involved here).

As I said, once the server verifies client credentials comes the **authorization** process. In this part of the process the security component checks if the current user has enough privileges to access the requested resource (URI). This is done in a role based model, when doing the authentication the user is given some role (an authenticated user is given by default an IS_FULLY_AUTHENTICATED role).

And now you may wonder, wow, this is great, but how does this fit in the configuration of my firewall? That's easy, the authorization part is ruled by the *security.firewalls* configuration entry whereas the authorization part is ruled by the *security.access_rules* (this is a simplification, see below).

Notice that if your application does not have any special authorization rules (you only need an authenticated user and no special privileges to access different resources), then you are good to go without any access rule (the authorization is based on the IS_FULLY_AUTHENTICATED role only). You may need specific roles in an admin panel for example.

Having said all that, the really cool thing about this two step process is that each step is isolated from the other. You can use whichever method you want for authentication (user/password form, HTTP basic authentication, API token, etc., etc.) and the authorization will work anyway.

To make things clearer (hopefully) a request goes like this:

1. Client request a resource (URI)
2. Firewall listener captures the request and if the URI is behind a protected path (this is checked using the *pattern* configuration parameter from the *firewall* section) the authentication process begin
3. In an API token authentication process you would typically check the token from a header (this is up to your implementation though) and if the token is valid, the user is authenticated and the role IS_FULLY_AUTHENTICATED (otherwise and exception is raised, the kernel takes care of it, so don't worry).
4. Now is the turn for the authorization manager. Its job is to ask: does the user need a special role to access the requested URI? (this is checked against the *pattern* parameter from the firewall section and the *access_rules* configuration parameter), if no access rules apply in the current request the only check is if the user is authenticated (which symfony will know because of step 3).

**So to answer your question**:

- there is no need to use a form login in order to protect a resource (URI), you can use any default method or create your own one (API token in your case), the authorization will work.
- You only need access rules if you're using role based access to URI, if you only require an authenticated user, you don't need access rules.

PS: Symfony Security Component is way more complex than that, I've done my best to give you an overview while trying to make things simple and clear (while omitting anonymous users, storing credentials in session and some complex cases as ACL and voters)

Comment: Editing original question to include the code I put in. In my instance, I will need access rules as I only want certain URIs to be accessed by different access levels. Looking at the http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html page, The code I put in it appears that the access rules were just being ignored. So I'm assuming I have this set up incorrectly.